# Uploding a profile picture in a React native Expo Application

Tags: node.js, image, react-native, expo

So, I have an expo application that the user can set his profile picture, but I'm having trouble to store the picture in my backend.
I'm using Node.js in the backend and i have 2 libraries which are `fs-extra` and `path`.

So When a user set his profile picture, what i get in the backend is this `file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540motaa%252FNatureApp/ImagePicker/783259e0-e3b5-41ee-8fd7-e03fd54425a0.jpg`
And i have tried to use a form to transfer the file but i couldn't get it to work so i stuck with this.

But now i don't know how to extract the picture so i can store it on my backend or even in my database.
This is the code i'm using to store the picture in a directory in the backend:

```
    const { image } = req.body;
    console.log(image);
    const newPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "../PostImages") + "/" + "image.jpg";
    await fs.move(image, newPath);
```

Frontend Code:

```
  const image = result;
  const data = new FormData();
  data.append("profilePicture", {
    name: "hello.jpg",
    type: image.type,
    uri:
      Platform.OS === "android"
      ? image.uri
      : image.uri.replace("file://", ""),
  });
  uploadUserImage({ data });
```

Request code:

```
const uploadUserImage = (dispatch) => {
  return async ({ data }) => {
    console.log(data);
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token");
    try {
      await axios({
        method: "post",
        url: "http://localhost:5000/userImg",
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer$${token}`,
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
        body: data,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: Change `"http://localhost:5000/userImg"` to `"http://localhost:5000/profile"`

Comment: But i'm making a request to userImage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `multer` which is great to save images on backend. If you are passing the form data you can use it, this is how you can add it:

```
<form action="/profile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="avatar" />
</form>
```

```
var express = require('express')
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })
 
var app = express()
 
app.post('/profile', upload.single('nameofImage'), function (req, res, next) {
  // req.file is the `avatar` file
  // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
})
```

For more details, you can check [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer).

Comment: The formData that i create is it supposed to look like this?
`FormData {
  "_parts": Array [
    Array [
      "profilePicture",
      Object {
        "type": "image",
        "uri": "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540motaa%252FNatureApp/ImagePicker/3432e00e-a958-49f9-9636-8eb64cd769ae.jpg",
      },
    ],
  ],
}`

Comment: It is because of the route you might be using in the frontend. can you add the frontend code in the question? Make sure you request at '/profile'

Comment: I have added the frontend code now and i don't have the error anymore i just get undifined in the backend

Answer (score 0):

For **React Native/Expo** projects, to upload/send a file to the backend you need to create a formData and use it in the Body of the request, like this

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('FileData', {
  name: 'FileData.jpg',
  uri: 'file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540motaa%252FNatureApp/ImagePicker/783259e0-e3b5-41ee-8fd7-e03fd54425a0.jpg',
  type: 'image/jpg', // mime type of file
});
```

Now perform a `request` to the backend with this formData in the body

Request Code would be

```
const uploadUserImage = (dispatch) => {
  return async ({ data }) => {
    console.log(data);
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token");
    try {
      await axios({
        method: "post",
        url: "http://localhost:5000/profile", // make sure URL is correct
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer$${token}`,
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
        body: data,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
};
```

And in the backend access the file  as shown below

```
var express = require('express')
var multer  = require('multer')
const upload = multer({ storage: multer.memoryStorage() });
 
var app = express()
 
app.post('/profile', upload.single('FileData'), function (req, res, next) {
  // access it with --> req.file
})
```

Comment: I get file "undifined"

Comment: In the backend i already had that so i still get undifined